# hide part of URL in browser with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a website , when client click to one of the website link this address is displayed in the browser :

```
https://site/page.php?id=324
```

324 is user id in my database , next user : 325 , ...
i want hide "?id=***" in browser with ".htaccess "
when client click to "page.php" only show "https://site/page.php" in browser URL .
any advise ?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it?

Comment: You can't hide the `id` parameter. If you do this then how will you db know what to retrieve. However you can rewrite your URL to make it look clean and SEO friendly something like `example.com/user/123` or `example.com/123` . The ID parameter is required to get info from db based on the id.